# On Hover : How to show a tool tip with copy option for all url's inside a textarea field in Extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I am new to ExtJs ,In this I have a textareafield binding data from API response.

What I want to do is if the response has any url's in it I would like to show a tool tip kind of thing with copy option when user hover on it.Can anyone help me to  get this .

code:

```
xtype: 'textareafield',
fieldLabel: 'Reponse',
name: 'response',
align: 'stretch',
allowBlank: false,
flex: 1

response.setValue(StringUtils.addHtmlBreaks(record.get('response')));
```

Thanks..

Comment: If I provide you answer for showing tip on textarea then can you handle any condition when to show it , because I am not getting URL logic. Please reply for same.

Comment: I need to show only when the hovered text is a url @Tejas inside the textarea

Comment: Only the hovered URL content with a copy option(clipboard) @Tejas

Comment: I am creating fiddle with your requirements. I will post this as answer, then you can check there.

Comment: okay Thanks @Tejas for your time ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created simple fiddle where I have shown one textarea and binded mouse events and shown tip accordingly in [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vh6) fiddle.

```
textarea.on('mouseover',function(evt,field){
  //Show tip if url matches
},this);

textarea.on('mouseout',function(){
  //just hide tip
},this);
```

and matched url in textarea by `text.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi)`

In this fiddle I haven't implemented copy thing because I want to confirm if this behavior fits for you. Please check and reply for same, and in case of any edits in code suggest same.

Comment: But I can't copy the url from the tool tip @Tejas

Comment: I will update answer after doing copy thing, I was just confirming whether you wanted this thing.

Comment: It showing entire content in the tooltip but I need to show only the Url's like www.something.com ,http:\\something ,http;\\something etc...